# Is there a way to add expression in RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("anyExpression")?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

can we add ID ends with selection expression like `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("@([id$=myId])");`
which will update all the DOM components ending with id 'myId'. i don't want to mention this expression in xhtml. The attached image shows the generated IDs.[DOM structure with generated IDs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ewk07.png). if I mention ID as `form:myTableLocalId:4:myId`
then it updates only single component. I want to update all the components ending with ID `'myId'`

Comment: _" i don't want to mention this expression in xhtml."_ Why not? And are the id's in a datatable? All in the same column I assume?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27107993/how-do-update-jsf-datatable-column-only help?

Comment: @Kukeltje thanks for the reply. _" i don't want to mention this expression in xhtml."_ because i have to decide whether to update these id's or not based on certain conditions at runtime. is there a provision to update the id's conditionally?

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is expecting jsf to identify all the dom elements and update the elements ending with some specific name unfortunately JSF is not providing such type of facilities it's containing logic so you need to write logic to find all the elements `ID` of the `DOM` elements then pass the ID and JSF will update them.
You can call a Javascript function and then in Javascript you can find all the id which is ending with your matching id and then update them since now you are having ID you can do it easily.

Comment: Update : as per your generated HTML if you will update `form:myTableLocalId` your issue should be solved, it will update all the elements which is present inside `myTableLocalId` i.e. it will update entire table, i guess that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Not if you have 1000 rows and 20 columns. Updating 20.000 components  and their wrapper (the datatable) is more than updating just 1000 components

Comment: Jsf does not have this, but for datatables OmniFaces comes to the rescue (assuming components with the same id are in the same column) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27107993/how-do-update-jsf-datatable-column-only